# I tried to use DBI gem to connect my PostgreSQL server

Tags: ruby, postgresql, dbi

I tried to use DBI gem to connect my PostgreSQL server.

Here is my code:

```
DBI.connect('DBI:Pg:DBNAME:IP', 'ROLE', 'PWD')
```

Here is an error message I got:

**NameError: uninitialized constant DBI::DBD::Pg::Database::PGError**

Did you mean?  TypeError
              DBI::Error

I have no problem when I use dbi to connect Mysql server.

```
dbn = DBI.connect('DBI:Mysql:DBNAME:IP', 'USERNAME', 'PWD')
```

I also update my all gems:
pg, dbi and dbd-pg.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use [unmaintained gem dbi](https://github.com/erikh/ruby-dbi), you can see the readme says no longer maintained. Instead use the [ruby pg gem](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg)